Custom search parameters: define and usage
How to define a custom search parameter(ex: based on an extension) in hapi-fhir plain server implementation? How to make it surface in the metadata, similar to defined search parameters?
I only found the below article for jpa server implementation. hapi jpa server custom search.I did not find any additional documentation for plain server implementation.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
